# QFN-like package identification

Tags: integrated-circuit, layout, chip-design

Can anybody identify this package? Looks like a sort of QFN to me but it's not square and I have not been able to find anything like it.

The chip itself is proprietary, no datasheet available for it.

I'd like to make a break-out board + perhaps some pins on such package are "standard"/often used as VCC/GND and similar - so that's why I'm after it.

Chip has 17 contacts on long side, 6 on short side, totaling 46 contacts.

Measures 7.5mm x 3mm.

Pictures of the chip + layout of the package on the PCB below.

[image: long side measurement]
[image: short side measurement]
[image]

Comment: I've used some rectangular QFN packages before, but with 28 pins. Maybe you should try to find one with 46 pins and base the footprint on that? If the IC is proprietary w/o datasheet there will be no way to tell using just a ruler anyway..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your pic of the "chip" there are traces visible on the bottom of the package. I would say that this is not a "chip" but rather a small piece of PCB with components mounted on it, then probably hidden under epoxy. PCB material can be standard or custom.

So, this would be a hybrid circuit perhaps, there is no way to know unless you want to pop the cap off it. While it looks like a QFN, it seems to be a totally custom device.

If you want to make a breakout board, you will have to replicate the footprint on the existing PCB. I guess a QFN footprint generator wizard could work, but pay attention to the five pads in the center which seem to correspond to five solder balls under the "chip". These must be connected to something, possibly to get rid of heat... make sure you don't forget them.

Soldering this will require hot air or an oven...